# Definite Double Integral Limits Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have been given this question as part of my calculus course:

Consider the double integral

$$\int_0^1\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\beta}\frac{1}{\sqrt{y\sin^2(x)}}\,dxdy$$

The question instructs me to evaluate this integral for $\frac{\pi}{2} < \beta < \pi$.

Could someone please explain what the question is actually looking for?

Comment: Is your integral $$\int_0^1\int_{\pi/2}^{\beta}\frac{1}{\sqrt{y\sin^2(x)}}\,dxdy$$ ??

Comment: Yes! @cjferes Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the integral is separable:

1. The integrand can be expressed as the multiplication of a function of (x) and a function of $y$:
   $$f(x,y)=g(x)\cdot h(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}=\frac{1}{|\sin(x)|}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$$

   2. The integral boundaries do not depend on the variables.

So, we have:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}&=&\int_{\pi/2}^{\beta}\frac{1}{|\sin(x)|}\,dx\cdot\int_0^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\,dy\\
&=&\int_{\pi/2}^{\beta}\frac{1}{|\sin(x)|}\,dx\cdot\Bigg(\frac{2}{3}y^{3/2}\Bigg|_0^1\Bigg)\\
&=&\int_{\pi/2}^{\beta}\frac{1}{|\sin(x)|}\,dx\cdot1\\
\end{array}$$
We know $\frac{\pi}{2}\leq\beta\leq\pi$, so $|\sin(x)|=\sin(x)\,\forall x\in\Big[\frac{\pi}{2},\beta\Big]$ and:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}&=&\int_{\pi/2}^{\beta}\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\,dx\\
&=&\int_{\pi/2}^{\beta}\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\,dx\\
&=&\int_{\pi/2}^{\beta}\csc(x)\,dx\\
\end{array}$$

This is a known integral, and as such I will not calculate it here (there's plenty of books and internet to search how to do it!), so
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}&=&\int_{\pi/2}^{\beta}\csc(x)\,dx\\
&=&\ln\Big(\tan\big(\frac{1}{2}x\big)\Big)\Bigg|_{\pi/2}^{\beta}\\
&=&\ln\Big(\tan\big(\frac{1}{2}\beta\big)\Big)-\ln\Big(\tan\big(\frac{\pi}{4}\big)\Big)\\
&=&\ln\Big(\tan\big(\frac{1}{2}\beta\big)\Big)-\ln\Big(1\Big)\\
&=&\ln\Big(\tan\big(\frac{1}{2}\beta\big)\Big)-0\\
&=&\ln\Big(\tan\big(\frac{1}{2}\beta\big)\Big)\\
\end{array}$$